# Connection Time and response Time In JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, timeout

How can I set the connection timeout or the Response Timeout in JMeter through the properties (JMeter/User/System) files? I can do it by adding an HTTP Request Defaults but I need to do it through the property files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can pass properties 
 1. pass by command line options
 2. pass by using properties files.

> To pass properties using command line options:

The flag to set a property is `-JpropertyName` The function to read a property is `${__P(propertyName)}`

> To pass properties using JMeter.properties file

Define a property in JMeter.properties file (i have defined a test property in the screenshot below)
[image]

To read the property you can use [__Property function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property)

for example `${__property(testproperty,value,)}` this statement reads the property named testproperty and stores it in JMeter variable "value"

[image]

You can also read properties from external file. For more info on reading properties from external files [read this article](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/)

For more info on JMeter command line options [follow this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/jmeter-command-line-options/)

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [HTTPHC4Impl.java](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPHC4Impl.java#L982)

```
int rto = getResponseTimeout();
if (rto > 0){
    requestParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, rto);
}

int cto = getConnectTimeout();
if (cto > 0){
    requestParams.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, cto);
}
```

and [HTTPAbstractImpl.java](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPAbstractImpl.java#L164)

```
protected int getConnectTimeout() {
    return testElement.getConnectTimeout();
}
```

There is no way to set the values via JMeter properties, you will have to continue using the HTTP Request Defaults.

However instead of hard-coding timeout values into the .jmx script you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

[image: JMeter set timeouts via properties]

Once done you will be able to define the values in *user.properties* file like:

```
connectTimeout=1
responseTimeout=1
```

Or via [`-J` command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -JconnectTimeout=1 -JresponseTimeout=1 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

If you don't pass the value it will default to `0` (no timeout)

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)